# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My server was down so I have missed several registrations.  Are these Android devices lost?  Or is there a way for these devices to register again?

Answer (score 1):

```
Are these Android devices lost?
```

AFAIK,Yes.

**Tip:**
You should take precaution in your android application while the device tries to register itself on your server.just store the `registration_id` in `SharedPreference` and try to register on your server at some time interval until the device get registered successfully.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Storing the registration_id in SharedPreference is a good idea.  Thanks!